# How to add a "virtual" USB storage online to a running VirtualBox guest?

Tags: virtualbox

Related to: [How to add a new SATA disk to a running VirtualBox guest?](https://superuser.com/questions/1168202/how-to-add-a-new-sata-disk-to-a-running-virtualbox-guest)

> The only thing you can do is attach USB Storage to the host, and it
>   will become visible in the guest too

**Question:** How can I add a virtual USB storage to a running VirtualBox guest? I don't want to use a physical flashdrive, just do it "virtually" and online!

By virtual I mean to "emulate" a USB flash drive, so I could at the end, online add a new storage for a running guest.

Comment: VirtualBox supports adding a virtual USB controller since version 6.1.x (it is in the same config page for adding SATA and SCSI controllers). There you can attach virtual (disk images) USB disks. Not sure about hot adding, I would guess hot adding the USB controller is not supported, while hot adding disks is. Also, the disk are not marked as type "Removable" but "Fixed". This means they can be partitioned in older Windows (Win10 allows partitioning in both cases). It also means some software will not recognize them as "USB keys".

Answer (score 2):

Impossible.

VirtualBox does not virtualize USB mass storage devices.

If you want to add mass storage to your virtual machine, the only way to power it down and add a virtual hard disk.

Comment: VirtualBox does in fact support hot-add (on appropriate controllers like SCSI/SATA with free ports), but it may be necessary to use the command line tools (`VBoxManage`) to do this.

Comment: @DanielB So what? It still doesn't virtualize a mass storage device.

Comment: “the only way to power it down and add a virtual hard disk.” Wrong. That’s what. ;)

Comment: @DanielB If there is indeed a workable solution, please post it. But since you haven't, it is quite obvious that there isn't. Whatever "hot-add" what-not support that VirtualBox offers is just a cute factoid, nothing more.

Comment: I have, on the OP’s other question. It doesn’t add USB storage, so it’s not applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

tested under virtualbox-5.2, 5.2.14-123301~Ubuntu~trusty

```
to detach a disk:
VBoxManage storageattach $host --storagectl "SATA" --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none

to attach a disk:
VBoxManage storageattach $host --storagectl "SATA" --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium test2.vdi
```

the "hot-pluggable" option must be checked in the storage controller section first.

granted this is not usb storage, but sata hdd and usb hdd are almost identical under linux.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test with earlier versions, but I have just tested with VirtualBox 7.0 and it *does* support virtual USB drives.

You can add a (virtual) **USB controller** under the **Storage** definition section of the virtual machine (just like a **floppy** or **IDE controller**). Then, you can create some virtual disks (`.vdi`) and after you boot your machine you can access the **Storage** section and dynamically add / remove those disks.